# Change material icon color on hover

Tags: css, material-design

I am using this [demo](http://www.getmdl.io/templates/dashboard/index.html) and want to change icons color on hover

```
.demo-navigation .mdl-navigation__link .material-icons:hover {
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

But didn't work. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you provide the html code of the element you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add !important on the color because the icon has a class (mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400) that adds the grey color with important also

Comment: basically this should work ``color: #FFF !important;``

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code:

```
    .demo-navigation .mdl-navigation__link:hover .material-icons {
      background-color: #00BCD4;
      color: #FFF;
    }
```

First you need to set the `:hover` on the link class not the icon class. Second you must use `!important` because there is a different class (`.mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400`) that is using `!important` that you must override.

Comment: in my case, the color `!important` mentioned in other solutions had no effect. Changing the location of the `:hover` clause is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400` class on the `i` tag will require you to use `!important` when changing it's color.

Answer (score 0):

in your css `:hover` rule add the `!important` keyword.

```
.your-icon-class {
  transition: all 300ms; // if you want the color to gradually change
}

.your-icon-class:hover {
  color: #FFF !important;
}
```