# Material Icons Hover CSS functionality

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, hover

I'm trying to add the hover effect to material icons but it does not work. I'm not sure what's going wrong. Everything else looks great but I'm unable to see the hover effect. I've added my code below.

```
import ManageAccountsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ManageAccounts';
import NotificationsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Notifications';
import HelpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Help';

const iconStyle =
{
    "fontSize": "25px",
    "color": "grey",
    "padding-right":"30px",
    "padding-top":"20px",
    "cursor":"pointer",
    "borderRadius": "10%",
    "&:hover": { "color": "black" }
}
<HelpIcon style={iconStyle}/>
                <NotificationsIcon style={iconStyle}/>
                <ManageAccountsIcon style={iconStyle}/>
```

Comment: Does this help? [Change material icon color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906935/change-material-icon-color-on-hover)

Comment: Pseudo-classes like `:hover` cannot be controlled via inline styles (i.e. the `style` prop). You would need to control it in a CSS class.

Comment: @isherwood I must admit. It seems that could help but I'm unable to add the important keyword to my inline style. Perhaps you could guide me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. This code works when you use the sx keyword instead of style. So this works

```
import ManageAccountsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ManageAccounts';
import NotificationsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Notifications';
import HelpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Help';

const iconStyle =
{
    "fontSize": "25px",
    "color": "grey",
    "padding-right":"30px",
    "padding-top":"20px",
    "cursor":"pointer",
    "borderRadius": "10%",
    "&:hover": { "color": "black" }
}
<HelpIcon sx={iconStyle}/>
<NotificationsIcon sx={iconStyle}/>
<ManageAccountsIcon sx={iconStyle}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use pseudoselectors (`&:hover`) in inline styles. This is not a limitation of React or Material UI but CSS itself.